HIMYM Episode where Marshall starts to get attracted to his co-worker?
What is the How I Met Your Mother episode where Marshall starts to get attracted to his co-worker because he's been with her for a very long time?

This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for help identifying a specific episode of a TV show that can easily be looked up using Google.

@MattD, whilst I agree with you entirely that this could (and obviously was) easily remedied by a google search, 'Identify-this-episode' is still on topic here, and actually has its own tag. This was voted on recently, and the discussion is now closed, so I'm afraid for the time being its here to stay.

I found it! It's the 11th episode from Season 6, The Mermaid Theory.
